Why does entering a second-level domain in Firefox (macOS Sequoia 15.1.1) URL bar not auto-complete to URLs with non-www subdomains?
In the Firefox URL bar (on macOS Sequoia 15.1.1), if I start typing a second-level domain (e.g., "google" for www.google.com), it will auto-complete as long as the subdomain of the website is "www". In these cases, it will just fill in the rest of the url without adding www, but it will be resolved correctly once I press enter. That's all fine.
However, there are some websites I visit semi-frequently with non-"www" subdomains. In these instances, Firefox will never autocomplete the url. For example, typing in "yahoo" will never auto-complete to "mail.yahoo.com". One must begin by starting to type the subdomain ("mail" in this example) for Firefox to autocomplete a url that doesn't start with "www", as far as I can tell. Starting by typing "yahoo" here results in "mail.yahoo.com" being the first url listed under the "Firefox suggest" heading, but selecting that requires pressing arrow keys or using the mouse, extra steps/time.
My question: is there any Firefox option I can select/change to expand Firefox autocomplete to urls with non-www subdomains when only typing in the relevant second-level domain?
I suppose this behavior could be seen as Firefox interpreting "auto-complete" very literally, only suggesting characters that come after those you've already entered in the url bar. This is reasonable, as truly auto-completing by adding text before and after the text already entered is problematic, but there are ways around that. For example, Chrome is not limited in this way.
In Chrome, if I frequently visit mail.yahoo.com, when I open a new tab and type in "yahoo" it will keep the text I've typed, but put a dash with the full suggested url after it. So the text you see in the url bar after having only typed "yahoo" will be "yahoo - mail.yahoo.com". Pressing enter at this point will take you to the full url. In Firefox, in the same scenario, typing in "yahoo" will have "mail.yahoo.com" be the first listed suggestion, but pressing enter will take you to your search engine's results for "yahoo".

I've tried in both Firefox and Chrome, and can't reproduce what you're describing.
For me, whatever I start typing gets handled in one of two ways.

Both Firefox and Chrome autocomplete the rest of the URL from the point I've reached, with the autocompleted section hightlighted.

Both Firefox and Chrome also provide suggestions which are displayed below the current address bar, so I can arrow down and select one of those suggestions as needed.


Nothing I tried leads to Chrome displaying an expanded address (for instance my equivalent of mail.yahoo.com when typing yahoo) after a - which can be selected by pressing enter.
But, even if that functionality does happen in your Chrome when you've visited a particular website frequently enough, there's no reason to expect Firefox to behave in the exact same way since they're entirely different browsers, written by completely different companies, and no doubt some users wouldn't want the browser to behave that way.


You're doing this by starting to type in the second-level domain for a url that does not have a "www" sub-domain?



Yes, I also get the suggested options. I was just hoping there would be a way to avoid having to arrow down. I'm aware they're different browsers and never said I expected Firefox to be exactly like Chrome in this way, but I do like that feature, so I wondered if Firefox could do something similar. There are many Firefox options dealing with url bar auto-correct, auto-fill, suggestions, etc., and I have experimented with some of them but wondered if there was something I missed.


Sorry to add another message here, but I realize now that in my original post, I did not specify my OS. I'm on MacOS 15.1.1. If you are using Firefox on Windows (or Linux), perhaps the differences in behavior we observed stem from this.

Ahhh, thanks yes that's useful to know. I tried on Windows, if I remember I'll see if I get the same at home on my Mac.
